# How to test async logic that contains Celery tasks?

Tags: python, celery, python-asyncio, django-celery, django-channels

In my particular case I am testing django-channels consumer that has some async Celery tasks with countdown, those play important role in logic. So, when testing obviously I can't wait for countdown of the task to pass. How can I mock those tasks to execute asynchronously but without countdown?

I tried couroutine mock that didn't work.

```
with mock.patch('apps.chat.tasks.kick_unready_students', new=CoroutineMock()):
        await trainer_communicator.send_json_to({
            'type': Actions.TRAINING_START,
        })
```